# How to delete table rows based on months of the date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table from csv file that has the dates of various data in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I am wondering how I would remove data that was is recorded within the months December to April. In other words, I would like to remove rows whose months are not 12, 01, 02, 03, and 04.

How would I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
exclude_months = [12,1,2,3,4]
df['Buoy 44017 Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Buoy 44017 Time'])

# remove rows 
new_df = df[df['Buoy 44017 Time'].dt.month.isin(exclude_months)]
```

Comment: This code actually does the opposite of what I excepted; it removes rows with months between December to April. However, this can easily be fixed by removing the ~ in the last line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def date_filter(dates):
    return [
        datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d").month not in (12,1,2,3,4)
        for date in dates
    ]

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

selected_rows = df.loc[ date_filter(df['Date']) ]
```

using the dataframe loc method to filter out the unwanted dates